# Inherited web server control can't find reference to parent assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.Net with Visual Studio 2012/.NET 4.5 and here's the situation:

I have an assembly with an abstract class that inherits from WebControl named CDASPControl, it contains various helper methods and such for other controls that inherit from it.

And I have an assembly called CDASPGrid that inherits from the aforementioned control.

When I drop the CDASPGrid into my web page, it adds the control just fine, and adds the register page directive with no problem:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CDASPGrid, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" Namespace="Controls" TagPrefix="cdc" %>

<cdc:CDASPGrid ID="CDASPGrid1" runat="server" />
```

When I go to compile my application I get the following error:

> type 'Controls.CDASPControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CDASPControl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.

In the references, the CDASPGrid reference is there, however the CDASPControl reference is not.

When I manually add the CDASPControl reference to the web site (it's a web project if that makes any difference) it compiles and runs just fine.

Is there anyway to get the web site to pick up the extra reference automatically without having to manually add it?

I've noticed 3rd party controls do this, for example the DevXPress ASP Gridview control will add any necessary references to the web.config as necessary.  Would someone be able to point me in the right direction so that I can learn how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, I had to handle this manually.  Using the EnvDTE assembly I was able to get the project references at design time via the control designer and have it add the missing reference to the project references.  Also, I was also able modify the web.config to add the assembly to the assemblies list via the control designer.

Not an ideal solution, but it works quite well.

Here's the article that got me on the path:
[How to register automatically HTTP handler required by a Web server control](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000686.html)